# AS3: using beginBitmapFill() with a library object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, graphics, bitmap, shapes

How can I setup a .beginBitmapFill() with a bitmap loaded into the movie's library? Every example I've found on the internet uses the loader class to load the bitmap externally, but I want to load it from the library instead.

I want to turn:

```
mesh.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF,1);
```

into

```
mesh.graphics.beginBitmapFill(..., null, true, false);
```

and have my shape filled with a tiled 'bitmap.bmp' loaded into the library. The major problem is how I can address the library bitmap inside the fill method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add the image file to your library and export it to ActionScript as a BitmapData object:

[image]

then you can write the graphics code like this:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Shape;

var mesh:Shape = new Shape();
mesh.graphics.beginBitmapFill(new MeshBitmapData(), null, true, false);
mesh.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
mesh.graphics.endFill();

mesh.x = mesh.y = 20;

addChild(mesh);
```

and you will get this:

[image]

Comment: Any idea how good on performance the 'beginBitmapFill()' is on Mobile Devices?